# Golang Generic+Variadic Function

Tags: go, generics, variadic

In Golang having a number of functions of some generic type

```golang
type Transformer[A, B any] func(A)(B, error)
```

How to define a Generic Variadic high order function that could compose such functions in general something as

```
func Compose[A,B,C....N any](transformers... Transformer[A,B], Transformer[B,C]...Transformer[M,N]) Transformer[A,N]
```

Comment: 1. You cannot do that, 2. because it make no sense and 3. isn't needed as you just need Compose on three types. (Additionaly The name of the language is Go. Use Lean or Coq or similar if you wan't to go crazy on functional and type system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, generic variadic functions are not yet supported. However, you can achieve a similar result by using variadic arguments and recursion.

Comment: Yah, I've ended up with one step iteration composer `type Composer[A,B, C any] func(ab Transformer[A, B], bc Transformer[B,  C]) C`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Volker; this is a silly thing to do in Go. I would suggest you post another question with a summary of the problem you're actually trying to solve with this construction and see if there's a way to solve you're problem that's more idiomatic.

All that being said, just for fun:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Composable[B, N any] func(in B) N

func Return[N any]() Composable[N, N] {
    return func(in N) N {
        return in
    }
}

func ToString[N any](next Composable[string, N]) Composable[int, N] {
    return func(in int) N {
        return next(fmt.Sprintf("%v", in))
    }
}

func Hello[N any](next Composable[string, N]) Composable[string, N] {
    return func(in string) N {
        return next(fmt.Sprintf("helloooo %s", in))
    }
}

func main() {
    f := ToString(Hello(Return[string]()))
    res := f(22)
    fmt.Printf("%v", res)
    // Output: helloooo 22
}
```

To be clear, if I saw this in a code review I would be very concerned.